# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-views, spotify

While running the app locally, I am able to get the result.

But while deploying on heroku, I am getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spotipy'

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "hello",
    "corsheaders",
    "spotipy", //added it over here
]
```

requirements.txt:

```
django
gunicorn
django-heroku
requests
spotipy
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Greeting
import requests
import json
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  uri = 'random artist'
  spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='confidential', client_secret = 'confidential'))
  artist = spotify.show(uri, market = "IN")
  return JsonResponse(artist)

def db(request):
  greeting = Greeting()
  greeting.save()

  greetings = Greeting.objects.all()

  return render(request, "db.html", {"greetings": greetings})
```

procfile:

```
web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi
```

I am new to front end development, kindly help

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the version in requirements.txt

```
spotipy==2.17.1
```

Comment: on build, it gives the following error: ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting. Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.

Comment: Please confirm the file is called `requirements.txt` (starting with lowercase) and it is in the root of the repo. Also please publish your Procfile

Comment: it is in lowercase only. And, after going through a couple of threads, I am now getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Django'. I am not able to solve this issue despite going through a lot of solutions

Comment: Do you set the version for Django (ie `Django>=2.0,<4.0`)?

Comment: I did not explicitly set a version for Django. The version installed is 2.2. I deleted the previous app, and created a new one. Problem has been solved. I still don't know why it was happening. Thanks for your help though